# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams.setSoKeepalive(Lorg/apache/http/params/HttpParams;Z)V

Tags: java, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am writing a servlet program to upload file to s3.

I have the following jars :

- apache-httpcomponents-httpcore
- aws-java-sdk-core-1.9.8
- aws-java-sdk-s3-1.9.0
- commons-fileupload-1.3
- framework_S3
- httpclient-4.2.3
- org.apache.commons.io
- org-apache-commons-logging

and I am facing the error : `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams.setSoKeepalive(Lorg/apache/http/params/HttpParams;Z)V`

I know this is due to jars, but If a remove one of my jars then I face some other errors.

What other jars I am missing.

Thank you

Comment: You likely have the wrong version of some jar; you compiled against a different version than you provided at runtime, and the class from the one at runtime doesn't have that method

Comment: what is the version of `httpcore` jar?

Comment: I directly downloaded from the following link :

[link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/Downloadapachehttpcomponentshttpcorejar.htm)